# VSCode hide top-right icons (in the tab bar)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm a big fan of VScode's minimalist approach, but one thing is bugging me. I would like to hide editor-tab icons.

[image]

The icons are from extensions: `git-lens` & `hexdump for VScode`. Also the split-editor icon would be nice to hide.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58244879/vscode-is-there-a-way-to-hide-top-action-menu-bar

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128867

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Extension [Custom CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css)

```css
.tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Optionally, show them on hover:

```css
.tabs-and-actions-container:hover .editor-actions {
    display: flex !important;
}
```

Comment: Is this solution still up to date?

Comment: @Joep I think this is the most up to date (working) answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266613/vscode-hide-top-right-icons#comment124800927_65066561

Answer (score 20):

I faced the same problem and Alex's answer helped me a lot (showing the icons on hover only).

But I still had an issue, especially when coding in a small window:

Let's say I want to open the file "styles.css" using the tabs bar:

[image]

As soon as my mouse enters the tabs zone, the menu shows up (because of the hover trick) and I can't click my tab because it's below the icons:

[image]

So I came up with this idea:

**Showing the icons bar *below* the tabs (not *over* the tabs) when hovering**

Here is the result:

[image]

Here is how I did it:

```
.tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions {
    display: none !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #2D2D2D;
}
.tabs-and-actions-container:hover .editor-actions {
    display: flex !important;
}
.title.tabs.show-file-icons {
    overflow: unset !important;
}
```

Comment: Excellent idea, this should have been the default behavior.

Comment: Thanks for this great solution. I used it as a base for [another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69788835/3018229) which moves the buttons down to the breadcrumb bar.

Answer (score 7):

I combined the answers of Vincent and mozlingyu to another solution: instead of hiding the buttons, move them down one level to the breadcrumb bar:

[image: icons in breadcrumb bar]

This is done using the [Customize UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui) extension (**Warning 2023**: [it may break your VS Code installation](https://github.com/iocave/customize-ui/issues/156#issuecomment-1434045323)) with the following configuration:

```
"customizeUI.stylesheet": {
    ".tabs-and-actions-container": {
        "background-color": "inherit",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions": {
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": "100%",
        "right": "0px",
        "height": "22px !important",
        "z-index": "1",
        "background-color": "inherit",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions .action-item": {
        "margin-right": "3px !important",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions .action-item a": {
        "font-size": "13px",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions .action-item .codicon": {
        "width": "13px",
        "height": "13px",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .tab:last-child": {
        "margin-right": "0 !important",
    },
    ".title.tabs.show-file-icons": {
        "overflow": "unset !important",
    },
}
```

This solution is theme-independent, so it should work for all colour combinations. The background color for the buttons is always the same as the background color of the tab bar. If you use only one static theme, you could hard-code the `background-color` for the `.tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions` selector to the exact color of the breadcrumb bar for a more seamless design. However, this does not work when switching themes.

The only drawback to this solution is that the buttons overflow the rightmost breadcrumb information, but I'm fine with that.

Comment: This was _precisely_ what I needed. Thank you very much

Comment: Great!I suggest  "background-color": "transparent" for ".tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions" by the way

Comment: @IceSea Thanks for the comment and the suggestion. Setting it to `transparent` definitely works and looks nice as long as the breadcrumbs are short. If they get longer and overlap with the buttons, you will have a hard time figuring out where which button is, so this is unfortunately not ideal.

Comment: @carlfriedrich transparent is good for pages other than editor (like settings), long breadcrumb is a real problem so I have ".tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions:hover" to get around that eventually, nevermind

Comment: @IceSea That sounds useful indeed!

Comment: This is the best solution yet. Please provide link to your [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/115136#issuecomment-1020126122) on the bug report, so people can vote.

Comment: @vanowm Thanks for your comment. There actually already was a link on the GitHub issue to my answer here. It may have been not that obvious, though, so I edited my comment over there slightly to make it clearer.

Comment: WARNNG: `Customize UI` extension now **brokes** VS Code installation: https://github.com/iocave/customize-ui/issues/156. To undo `Monkey Patch` extension (installed automatically too) breaking changes go to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out` and restore `*.js` files from backup files in this folder.

Comment: Achieved something similar with non-breaking [Custom CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css) extension: https://gist.github.com/d9k/e85e08b17fc79b080cb81b8e9a113a65

Answer (score 4):

**Without extensions**

1. Open default css file that vs-code reads to render its window

```
cd /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench
sudo vim workbench.desktop.main.css # or whatever editors but vs-code
```

2. Add this line at the end and save it

```
.editor-actions { display: none }
```

**To identify class names of elements**,

just press `ctrl + shift p` and type `toggel developer tools`

Comment: Note you get an error message about corrupt files. You can click the Cog icon and ignore. You get the same warning with the extension Custom CSS and JS Loader. So this solution has less overhead, doing the same thing.

Comment: On windows the file is here: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench`

Comment: nice solution! the extensions always stop working for me after updates. this is much, much better.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a better extension for this.
[Customize UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui)

Comment: Combining this with Vincent's answer, the idea is to add the following lines to the settings after installing Customize UI:
`
  "customizeUI.stylesheet": {
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions" : "display: none !important; position: absolute; top: 20px; right: 0; z-index: 1; background-color: #2D2D2D;",
    ".tabs-and-actions-container:hover .editor-actions": "display: flex !important;",
    ".title.tabs.show-file-icons" : "overflow: unset !important;"
  }
`

Answer (score 4):

Gitlens icons can be disabled within the extension settings:

https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/issues/669#issuecomment-540975432

Comment: `"gitlens.menus": false,` in `settings.json`

Answer (score 3):

###### Editor Actions Position

In Insiders now and probably Stable v1.85 is the ability to hide all those icons (`hidden`) or move them to the Title Bar or the Tab Bar.  The Tab Bar is the default location where they start and is to the right of the last tab.

The built-in icons for `Split` and `More...` will be moved as well as any extension icons.

There is a context menu in the Tab Bar that has the options, see demo:

[image: editor actions position demo]

---

In v1.72 now is the ability to hide/show any of the icons on that toolbar, see [/hide menuItems](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/160993).

[image: remove tab toolbar icons]

Answer (score 0):

Building on @teraoka's answer, you might like to keep a script to do this since the setting will revert each time VSCode updates itself

Using a Git-bash / cygwin:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /c/Users/noel/appdata/local/Programs/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/
cp workbench.desktop.main.css workbench.desktop.main.css.`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`
echo ".editor-actions { display: none }" >> workbench.desktop.main.css
```