# How to disable resizing of editor actions panel in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode has "editor actions" panel to the right of the tab bar, that displays  buttons for actions such as "Open Changes" or "Split Editor Right".

[image: editor actions]

This panel also dynamically adds other buttons depending on currently active file type, such as "Open Preview to the Side" for markdown files. I dislike this behavior because it makes the width of the tab bar change from file to file and makes tabs jump.

[image: jumping tabs]

I have searched in VSCode settings but couldn't find any way to control this. I think I should be able to hide the editor panel completely by overriding editor styles but I would prefer to only disable the dynamic part of it. Is there a way to do that?

I'm using VSCode 1.31 on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found to this problem has been to remove the buttons. This can be done a couple of ways. Both of which I found on [this VS Code GitHub Issues thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46403).

1. [ashrafhadden's solution](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46403#issuecomment-411604090) (using the extension ["Custom CSS and JS Loader"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css)):
   [image: screenshot of ashrafhadden's solution as of 2019-12-18]
2. [ronjouch's solution](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46403#issuecomment-462935343) (requiring no extensions, but by opening up the Developer Console and running a command each time you open a VS Code window):
   [image: screenshot of ronjouch's solution as of 2019-12-18]

[This question titled "VSCode hide top-right icons"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266613/vscode-hide-top-right-icons) also has some answers in the same spirit as the ones I've shared above, but new answers may have been added since writing this.

Answer (score 0):

I had success using the [Customize UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui) extension by moving the buttons down one level to the breadcrumb bar:

[image: icons in breadcrumb bar]

This is done using the following configuration:

```
"customizeUI.stylesheet": {
    ".tabs-and-actions-container": {
        "background-color": "inherit",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions": {
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": "100%",
        "right": "0px",
        "height": "22px !important",
        "z-index": "1",
        "background-color": "inherit",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions .action-item": {
        "margin-right": "3px !important",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions .action-item a": {
        "font-size": "13px",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions .action-item .codicon": {
        "width": "13px",
        "height": "13px",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .tab:last-child": {
        "margin-right": "0 !important",
    },
    ".title.tabs.show-file-icons": {
        "overflow": "unset !important",
    },
}
```

This solution is theme-independent, so it should work for all colour combinations. The background color for the buttons is always the same as the background color of the tab bar. If you use only one static theme, you could hard-code the `background-color` for the `.tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions` selector to the exact color of the breadcrumb bar for a more seamless design. However, this does not work when switching themes.

The only drawback to this solution is that the buttons overflow the rightmost breadcrumb information, but I'm fine with that. At least the tab bar does not resize anymore, while I still have those buttons.