# VSCode: Is there a way to hide top action menu bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, is there a way to hide the *top action menu bar* that appears in the tabs row? I rarely use it and I find that it crowds the already limited space available to browse through open tabs. Moreover, its presentation is also inconsistent, especially when split panes are activated.

I'm not sure if I am referring to this VSCode functionality properly, so here's a screenshot demonstrating what I'm talking about (file names had to be blurred out due to NDA reasons):

[image: vscode top action menu bar]

Thank you.

Comment: I don't recognize the icons before the split editor icon.  Are they added by an extension?  What kind of file precedes those arrow thingy icons?

Comment: It's a JS file right before these icons and these icons will appear when I have any JS file in focus. The icons are for, in order from left to right: Open Changes, Run Code, Open Changes With Previous Revision, Show Revision Details, Open Changes with Next Revision, Toggle File Blame Annotations, Split Editor Right, More Actions.

So, looks like most of these actions are for git. Maybe an extension like gitlens is bringing these in?

Comment: Probably, disable the extension(s) one by one til you find it.  And then maybe there is a setting for it to hide or move those icons.

Comment: This is really annoying, it's not gitlens nor any other extension, this little actions section is part of vscode itself because i disabled all extensions and still it's right there (with fewer icons).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73807466/836330 for how to hide any of those icons.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Update 2022-09-28

[An issue to address this feature has been completed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/161802) and it will arrive with the next release. It is already available on the Insiders version.

This closed issue [references another feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/154804) different from the original one referenced on this answer.

### Context

It is called **editor actions** and, within the standard/native VSCode settings, you cannot hide it.

A setting to hide this annoying bar is an [open issue at VScode's GitHub since March 2018](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/46403).

### Fixes

##### Removing the whole bar

I feel your pain. This worked for me:

1. Install the [Customize UI extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui).
2. Open your user settings JSON:
   `cmd + shift + P` / `ctrl + shift + P`
   [image: Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)]
3. Add this setting:

```json
  "customizeUI.stylesheet": {
    ".editor-actions": "display: none !important;",
  },
```

It is gone!

##### Removing specific icons, by position

The foremost left icon is the number `1`.

*Example in plain CSS:*

```css
.menu-item-action-item-icon-1,
.menu-item-action-item-icon-3 {
  display: none !important;
}
```

*Example using Customize UI extension:*

```json
  "customizeUI.stylesheet": {
    ".menu-item-action-item-icon-1": "display: none !important;",
    ".menu-item-action-item-icon-3": "display: none !important;",
  },
```

##### Removing just Gitlens icons

Gitlens icons can be hidden within Gitlens' settings:

```json
"gitlens.menus": {
    "editorGroup": {
        "blame": false,
        "compare": false
    },
},
```

Comment: I don't see anything happening on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/46403. This solution still seems to be the easiest one.

Comment: You can now hide each button individually by right clicking. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74087078/263268

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a slightly different approach: instead of hiding the buttons, move them down one level to the breadcrumb bar:

[image: icons in breadcrumb bar]

This is done using the [Customize UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui) extension with the following configuration:

```
"customizeUI.stylesheet": {
    ".tabs-and-actions-container": {
        "background-color": "inherit",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions": {
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": "100%",
        "right": "0px",
        "height": "22px !important",
        "z-index": "1",
        "background-color": "inherit",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions .action-item": {
        "margin-right": "3px !important",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions .action-item a": {
        "font-size": "13px",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions .action-item .codicon": {
        "width": "13px",
        "height": "13px",
    },
    ".tabs-and-actions-container .tab:last-child": {
        "margin-right": "0 !important",
    },
    ".title.tabs.show-file-icons": {
        "overflow": "unset !important",
    },
}
```

This solution is theme-independent, so it should work for all colour combinations. The background color for the buttons is always the same as the background color of the tab bar. If you use only one static theme, you could hard-code the `background-color` for the `.tabs-and-actions-container .editor-actions` selector to the exact color of the breadcrumb bar for a more seamless design. However, this does not work when switching themes.

The only drawback to this solution is that the buttons overflow the rightmost breadcrumb information, but I'm fine with that. At least the tab bar does not resize anymore, while I still have those buttons.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using Customize UI and not getting the icons to disappear after targeting `".editor-actions"`, I was able to get the action icons to disappear by selecting `".monaco-toolbar"`:

```
"customizeUI.stylesheet": {
   ".monaco-toolbar": "display: none !important"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi there  I removed the GitLens plugin and it disappeared

Comment: Did not work for me. As of 2023-10-25, I can right click on the individual actions in the editor actions bar (or whatever it's called), and hide each one individually. All that remains is the "..." menu item. That seemed good enough for me.