# What is that component on the top-right of VS Code called? How can I change the setting of it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code on Mac and I was curious about one component.

Every time I open a new python file, this component will show up on the top right of the current window? But I can't find the name of it.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73807466/836330 for how to hide any of those icons.

Comment: @Mark I see you're a gold badge holder for [tag:vscode]. Maybe this should just be closed as a duplicate of that? My answer is continuously becoming outdated anyway.

Comment: @GinoMempin I understand, and any future questions on this topic I would close.  I am always a little hesitant to close dups of old questions and I think your answer has value as those pictured icons represent various sources which I don't think everyone would realize and that some of them can be handled en masse by an extension  setting.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's not just "one component", but actually multiple buttons added to the **editor actions** toolbar from multiple extensions installed on your VS Code.

[image]

In order from left to right:

1. Open Changes (built-in with VS Code as part of their Version Control functions)
2. Run Python File in Terminal (added by Microsoft's own [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension)
3. Open Changes in previous revision (added by the [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) extension)
4. Show Revision Details (added by the [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) extension)
5. Open Changes in next revision (added by the [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) extension)
6. Toggle File Blame Annotations (added by the [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) extension)
7. Split Editor (built-in with VS Code)

For GitLens, they are automatically added when it detects the currently opened file is part of a git repository. You can configure them by accessing the command palette (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on a Mac), then entering "*GitLens: Open Settings*". Find the "*Menus & Toolbars*" section:

[image]

For example, if you want to remove buttons 3., 4., and 5., uncheck "*Add commands to the editor group toolbar*" > "*Add comparison commands*". **Then reload VS Code**. You can configure all the other settings there.

For the green Play button, it automatically appears when you the currently active file is a Python file. AFAIK, there is no way to configure or hide/remove it other than disabling the Python extension completely (which you certainly *don't* want to do). There are requests on VS Code's Github page to hide it, like this: [Add setting to disable icon for "Run Python File In Terminal"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6921).

For the "Open Changes" and "Split Editor" buttons, AFAIK there is no built-in way to hide/remove them. You can only control the behavior from the VS Code settings:

[image]

As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59120736/what-is-that-component-on-the-top-right-of-vs-code-called-how-can-i-change-the#comment106492926_59231976), there is a feature request for VS Code to [Allow hiding the buttons in the tab bar line and in the panel title bar](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/46403), which includes the "Open Changes" and "Split Editor" buttons. There are users who provided workarounds at hiding the buttons using extensions. You may want to follow that thread and/or try out some of those extensions.

Comment: For anyone looking to hide all of these buttons outright, there’s an [open GH issue for this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46403) and if you don’t fancy waiting for a native fix, [one of the comments](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46403#issuecomment-523286973) includes info on disabling them via an extension.

Comment: @gino-mempin the leftmost button - "1. Open Changes" - is from vscode.git not gitlens. Unfortunately I don't know how to remove it :/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73807466/836330 for how to hide any of those icons, including the built-in and gitlens icons.

Comment: It works Open changes with Previous Revision