# How to reduce number of icons in tab bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Well, I do not StackOverflow this is the best place for my question, but this is where I landed after clicking on "ask questions" in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved

The icons pointed by the arrow are too many: on my 15" notebook, when the editor pane is split, depending on which tab is selected, I cannot read the full titles of three open tabs.

I would like to reduce their number or, if I can't, totally remove them. They have been added by an extension (related to git) that I find very convenient to have, so I would like to keep the extension, but to remove the icons.

[image]

I have:

- read https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface
- read https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes
- looked into `settings.json` for "icons"
- searched stackoverlow

plus many other, mainly random, attempts.

I could not find a way.

Any help?

Comment: add a feature request to make them optional, and show them in the `...` menu, I will star the request because I never use them.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73807466/836330 for how to hide any of those icons.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73807466/836330 for how to hide any tab bar icons or move them to the Title Bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're added by GitLens. You can remove them with `"gitlens.menus": false` in settings.json.

Comment: Thank you. I had searched for `gitlens` in `settings.json`, but there were no occurrences.